# How can I authenticate with Azure using a mobile app without relying on interactive sign-in?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-security, azure-entra-id

How do I authenticate with Azure, using a mobile app (without relying on interactive sign-in)?

**Expectations:**

As I understand, the following values are required for authenticating with Azure resources prior to invoking them:

•   TenantId
•   ClientId
•   Secret
•   Scope

**Issue:**

The following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/xamarin-forms/authentication) suggests that a mobile app user is required to manually authenticate with Azure before using the mobile app.

In my case, the mobile app itself is intended to be the user/client of Azure resources. Thus, I do not want to confuse an end-user with a sign-in window to use Azure resources.

I expected TenantId, ClientId, Secret, and Scope to be all that is required for the mobile app to authenticate (without an interactive sign-in for the end-user).

**Summary:**

In conclusion, how can I authenticate with Azure using a mobile app without relying on interactive sign-in?

**Client:**

```
var tenantId = <some value>;
var clientId = <some value>;
var secret   = <some value>;
var scope    = "https://management.azure.com/.default";

WebGateway.authToken = await BearerToken.Create(tenantId, clientId, secret, scope);

var serviceKeysResponse = await WebGateway.postToAsync(someBaseUrl, someResource, somePayload);
...
```

**Bearer Token:**

```
public static class BearerToken
{
    public async static Task<string> Create(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string scope)
    {
        var tokenRequestBody = new Dictionary<string, string> {

        { "grant_type"   , "client_credentials" },
        { "client_id"    , clientId },
        { "client_secret", clientSecret },
        { "scope"        , scope }
        };

        var url      = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        var client   = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
        var content  = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequestBody);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var tokenResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var valueFor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(tokenResponse);

            return valueFor.access_token;
        }

        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public int ext_expires_in { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HTTP Request:**

```
let postToAsync (baseAddress:string) (resource:string) (payload:Object) =

    task {
    
        let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan(0,3,0));
        let token = tokenSource.Token;
        
        try
            Debug.WriteLine $"\n\nAttempting HTTP Post: {baseAddress}{resource}" 

            use client = httpClient baseAddress
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization <- AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

            let  json     = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload)
            let  content  = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            let! response = client.PostAsync(resource, content, token) |> Async.AwaitTask

            Debug.WriteLine $"\n\n{response.StatusCode}:\n{baseAddress}{resource}\n\n" 
 
            return response

        with ex ->

            Debug.WriteLine($"\n\nError: {baseAddress}{resource}\n{ex.GetBaseException().Message}")

            if ex.GetBaseException().Message = "timeout" || ex.GetBaseException().Message = "A task was canceled"
            then return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
            else return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    }
```

Comment: So you would hard-code the client secret in the app? Users of your app would be able to extract this secret either from the app package or by intercepting network traffic. This is usually not a desired thing. The reason that the documentation says you need interactive authentication is because it isn't possible to securely authenticate the app itself as it runs in an untrusted environment. But we can require the user to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using OAuth2 under the hood.

The application have to implement one workflow to retrieve an *authorization* token, which is not the workflow to authenticate a user. This is left to the authorization server and unspecified, most provider implements OpenID Connect that makes your application redirect to the identity provider website (Google, Amazon, Facebook, Apple, Microsoft, StackExchange, ...). I think that your toolkit is implementing all the complicated stuff for you by the look of your code samples.

> I expected TenantId, ClientId, Secret, and Scope to be all that is required for the mobile app to authenticate (without an interactive sign-in for the end-user).

You are authenticating the OAuth2 client: the mobile application. I don't know your exact use-case but client ran on untrusted (consumer) systems should be public clients that doesn't carry a secret. You should evaluate if you need, in OAuth2 definitions, a *public* or *confidential* client.

> In conclusion, how can I authenticate with Azure using a mobile app without relying on interactive sign-in?

There are possible ways but you will certainly drastically lower authentication strengths and security.
I think you are in a XY problem and want instead to solve this problem.

> Thus, I do not want to confuse an end-user with a sign-in window to use Azure resources.

**I suggest that you inform the user that they are going to authenticate on Azure resources.** Then they won't be confused by going into the third-party authentication workflow. Authentication is hard to get right, focus on the application instead and let your third-party handle that for you.

This way is much more secure and flexible than passwords, where current best practices are to pair these with OTP, secure key, biometry or whatever additional factor you would have to implement since a secure provider won't offer password only authentication.

[image: OAuth2 workflow]